# Capture the text using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching, lookbehind, capturing-group

I have a text where I need to capture the second group

```
Response on your Property Listing 
Dear Rahul Bond, 
A user is interested in your Property, ID 62455995: 2 BHK , Multistorey 
Apartment in Raheja Vihar , Mumbai. 
Details of Contact Made: 
Sender's Name: Test (Individual)
```

The text to be retrieved is **2 BHK , Multistorey Apartment in Raheja Vihar , Mumbai.** This does start with **A user is interested in your Property, ID xxxxxxx: **

```
A user is interested in your Property, ID 62455995: 2 BHK , Multistorey 
    Apartment in Raheja Vihar , Mumbai.
```

The expected output is **2 BHK , Multistorey Apartment in Raheja Vihar , Mumbai.**

I have tried with `.match(/(A user is interested in your Property, ID.*[^:]) (.*\n.*)/g)`
Unfortunetly it gives me all 2 lined text.

Comment: Then you can replace the "A user is interested in your Property, ID 62455995: " by empty string to get the final string.

Comment: I would like to achive by using capture groups and using replace doesnt work for my use case.

Comment: How about more generically looking for ... `ID`, followed by a whitespace (sequence), followed by a sequence of 8 digits, followed by a single colon, followed by another whitespace (sequence) and then capturing anything which is not a dot/period including the first occurring dot/period ... [`/ID\s+\d{8}\:\s+(?<description>[^.]+\.)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uDFHaV/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```js
const text = `Response on your Property Listing 
Dear Rahul Bond, 
A user is interested in your Property, ID 62455995: 2 BHK , Multistorey 
Apartment in Raheja Vihar , Mumbai. 
Details of Contact Made: 
Sender's Name: Test (Individual)`;
const rgx = /(?<=A user is interested in your Property, ID \d+: )(.*\n.*)/g;

const result = text.match(rgx);
console.log(result);
```

It works here https://regexr.com/6tulh

Comment: `ID \d+:` id will be dynamic

Comment: I have updated the regex :D

Comment: updated the answer a short note on `positive look behind` and wont work with safari will be useful to OP.

Answer (score 2):

From the above comment ...

> *"How about more generically looking for ... `ID`, followed by a whitespace (sequence), followed by a sequence of 8 digits, followed by a single colon, followed by another whitespace (sequence) and then capturing anything which is not a dot/period including the first occurring dot/period ... [`/ID\s+\d{8}\:\s+(?<description>[^.]+\.)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uDFHaV/1)"*

... and making use of the proposed regex ...

```js
const multilineText =
`Response on your Property Listing 
Dear Rahul Bond, 
A user is interested in your Property, ID 62455995: 2 BHK , Multistorey 
Apartment in Raheja Vihar , Mumbai. 
Details of Contact Made: 
Sender's Name: Test (Individual)`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/uDFHaV/1]
const regX = /ID\s+\d{8}\:\s+(?<description>[^.]+\.)/g;

// either ...
console.log(
  [...multilineText.matchAll(regX)]
    .map(({ groups: { description } }) => description)
);

// or ...
console.log(
  [...multilineText.matchAll(regX)]
  [0]?.groups.description
);

// ... or ...
console.log(
  regX
    .exec(multilineText)
    ?.groups.description
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```